# C# linq grouping with same name

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I've a data table like

```
Date      status       recno
---------------------------------
2012      DST;Par        1
------------------------------------
2012      DST            2
--------------------------------
2012      DST            3
--------------------------------------------
2012      DST;Ts         4
-----------------------------------
```

Currently I have written a query like this:

```
var data = from b in table.AsEnumerable()
           where b.DateInterval>=fromDate && b.DateInterval<=toDate
           group b by b.Channel1_status into g                       
           select new
           {
               AccountNo=accountNumber,
               Status = statusLabels[g.Key].ToString(),
               StatusCount = g.Count(),
           };
```

However, it's returning me results these results:

```
Result: DST-2 
        DST;par-1 and DST;Ts-1

Expected: DST-4  DST;par-1 and DST;Ts-1
```

Please explain to me what I'm doing wrong and how to get the expected results.

Comment: I suspect your table hasn't got the information you think it has, or you're using a more complicated query which is using joins or something like that.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: It's not complicated query just grouping the column channel status and getting the result as i explained below. But the thing is i 've to get the result as i expected above.

Comment: The result you got looks correct to me. It groups by status, and you only have 2 rows with status "DST".

Comment: @CuongLe please take a look at Expected as i posted above, also the actual result what i'm getting now.

Comment: @Botz3000 Yes you're correct but the names starting with DST comes one group whether it can 've ;par or ;ts like this extra string into it.

Comment: What is `statusLabels`??

Comment: @Enigmativity It's a hashtable converting codes into text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to count all with a status starting with DST and still group the variations (DST;par, DST;ts), you could do it manually.

Something like this (not tested, but i think you get the idea):

```
var dst = data.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Status == "DST");
if (dst != null) {
    foreach (var group in data.Where(x => x != dst && x.Status.StartsWith("DST")) {
        dst.StatusCount += group.StatusCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's showing that here 'Except(dst)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @nag Yes, figured that it might not work immediately as it was just an example to get the idea across. However, i edited the code sample so that the error should be gone.

Comment: @nag It's because the type used is an anonymous type. If you create your own class holding the same three properties, you can make them writeable.

Comment: what if we converted into data table, because i already converted into data table.